# Why isn't the stylesheet variable being passed from this Jekyll _config.yml file?

Tags: html, css, yaml, jekyll

I want all the files in the post folder to use the posts.nest.sass.css stylesheet, so I tried putting that in as a default in the _config.yml file

```
defaults:
-
 scope:
  path: "_posts"
 value:
  layout: "post"
  stylesheet: "css/posts.nest.sass.css"
```

Then in post.html, which is the layout file for these posts I included this in the head:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{site.stylesheet}}">
```

In the generated page there is nothing inside the href attribute. How should this be written so the stylesheet variable is passed in?

I have not been able to find documentation about how this should be done, I just guessed. Links to good places to learn about formatting in Jekyll would be appreciated.

Edit: After more fiddling, including running the file through this [YAML linter](http://www.yamllint.com/), I abandoned putting this in the _config.yml file, and instead just filled in the href info directly - which up reflection is fine, since it isn't going to change with any of the posts and the layout file will fill it in. However the jekyll server says every time I save that there is invalid front-matter:

```
 Defaults: An invalid front-matter default set was found:
{"scope"=>{"path"=>"", "type"=>"posts"}, "value"=>{"layout"=>"post"}}
```

I'm putting in the whole file now in case a syntax error elsewhere is the 
issue, though I can't see it.

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
      type: "pages"
    values:
      layout: "default"
      stylesheet: "css/content.nest.sass.css"
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
      type: "posts"
    value:
      layout: "post"

destination: docs
exclude:
  - archive
  - graphics
  - webplayer
  - browsergame
  - blend4web
  - details-shim-master
  - blenderstuff
  - working
  - LICENSE.txt
  - README.md
  - TODO.txt
  - basetemplate.html
markdown: kramdown
url: "https://www.moonwards.com/"
```

Comment: Make sure you use `values` instead of `value` on your defaults declaration. `value` won't work and trigger that "An invalid front-matter default set was found" error.

Comment: @danirod thanks! I'm so awful at catching these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your default values are added to every posts variables, like the ones in front matter. So, the right syntax is :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{page.stylesheet}}">
```